# Introspecting an elixir macro after expansion and how it's defined

Tags: elixir

So in the docs for `defmacro` in Elixir we have (I put in a `hello` method for example purposes):

```
defmodule MyLogic do
  defmacro unless(expr, opts) do
    quote do
      if !unquote(expr), unquote(opts)
    end
  end

  def hello, do: "hello"
end
```

Then if I try to introspect on available functions, only hello/0 shows.

```
iex(3)> MyLogic.__info__(:functions)
[hello: 0]
```

But calling:

```
MyLogic.unless false do
  IO.puts("It works")
end
```

does invoke the macro.

My understanding is that the macro is expanded into final AST form and there is no trace of it once it is compiled. What I'm finding a bit confusing is that it seems you can invoke `unless` like a function but there's no trace of it in the introspection `.__info__(:functions)`.

1) I think you cannot introspect on macro definitions post-compilation because there's no trace of it after compilation, but in building a mental model of "unless" after it is expanded, how should I represent it in my mind? Should I just look at it as "MyLogic" now has this atom name `unless` that invokes the result of the if expression `if !unquote(expr), unquote(opts)`.
2) And how does Elixir know then that `unless` is a shortcut to the fully expanded macro code?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#c:__info__/1), the `:functions` atom is used to retrieve the functions of a module only.

If you want to get the macros instead, you should supply the atom `:macros` to `__info__/1` instead.

Since you can't have a macro and a function that share both the same name and arity, this makes it easy for Elixir to distinguish between the two.

Comment: ok thanks, I just read that a macro in Elixir is actually a function, so this explains how it can be invoked as if it were a function...do you know where in the elixir source code the functionality to allow macros is defined?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/691460a6e661f174476c69153776cba2f8a47341/lib/elixir/src/elixir_bootstrap.erl) as a starting point. You'll need to know Erlang btw. Also try executing `Kernel.__info__(:macros)` in an iex session. I believe you'll find the results interesting.

Answer (score 0):

@TGO already gave a perfect answer on why `__info__(:functions)` does not show `unless`; I still think there is some clarification required.

---

> My understanding is that the macro is expanded into final AST form and there is no trace of it once it is compiled.

**That is indeed very true.** The thing is Elixir is compiling everything before execution, and by writing `MyLogic.unless ...` you by no mean *call/invoke* the macro. What happens, you instruct Elixir to inject the AST returned by `MyLogic.unless` into your code instead of `MyLogic.unless`, *during compilation of your code*. There is no trace of the macro in the resulting BEAM.

> how should I represent it in my mind?

```
MyLogic.unless false, do: IO.puts("It works")
```

is expanded exactly into:

```
if !false, do: IO.puts("It works")
```

`unquote` is necessary there in macro declaration under `quote do` call because macros do receive *quoted expressions* as arguments. You might try to `IO.inspect/2` arguments *inside a call to macro*, outside of the `quote do`:

```
defmacro unless(expr, opts) do
  IO.inspect({expr, opts}, label: "compilation time!")
  quote, do: if !unquote(expr), unquote(opts)
end
```

> how does Elixir know then that `unless` is a shortcut to the fully expanded macro code?

There is a truly remarkable explanation of how Elixir maintains internal info on compilation stage which this margin is too small to contain. In general, Elixir *does not know anything*. You should clearly distinguish *compilation time* and *runtime* contexts. You are talking about *execution*. That happens *after everything is compiled* and your custom `MyLogic.unless/1` does not exist anymore, substituted by the AST injected.

Elixir cannot execute not compiled code, it’s not a scripting language. Don’t get fooled by REPL: **`iex` under the hood effectively compiles everything** you “execute” there before *real* execution.

> that a macro in Elixir is actually a function <sub>*(from your comments to another answer)*</sub>

This is by no means correct. Functions do exist as code that gets executed by *ErlangVM* in the resulting BEAM (after compilation passed.) Macros **do not**.